# Is there a way to allow for implicit conversions in c++?

Tags: c++, c

I need to use pieces of a C library in a C++/CLI project. I forced the c files to compile as c++, the problem is that the library uses a lot of implicit enum to integer comparisons which c++ wont allow. Now I could just properly cast all of these but I'd like to achieve the result without modifying the original library code if possible (since the library is still being developed and I'd like to have plug n play capability). Is there a way to allow c++ to implicitly convert those enums?

Comment: May you post some code/example?

Comment: Why not just compile C code with a C compiler, then link its functions as extern C into your C++ project?

Comment: Yeah that should work out of the box..

Comment: @BaummitAugen Sorry, I failed to specify that the pieces I want to use are part of a .exe tool in that library rather than a library project. What I'm doing is referring the .c and .h files from the tool project to my project within the same solution.

Comment: Why do you force them to compile as C++? If the headers are missing `extern "C"`, you can put that bit in wrapper files and use those instead.

Comment: Afaik local c code isn't allowed in the project when compiling to clr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pedant answer is **No**.

The C++ Standard is stricter than the C Standard in that regard, and implicit casts from integer to enumerator or from `void*` to `T*` do not work out of the box.

---

You have a couple solutions ahead of you:

- your *compiler* might have such a switch, it is not rare to have compiler switches to trigger non-Standard behaviors (often seen as "features"); I do not know of such switch but there are so many...
- you could compile C code as C (possibly linking into a separate library if necessary)
- you could edit the C code so it compiles as both C and C++
- and finally, since it is a library in development, you could ask the authors to make sure their code compile as both C and C++

Comment: "you could compile C code as C" - that. Since C and C++ have so many (not always) subtle differences, it's almost always to preferable to compile C code as C.

Comment: In the end, turns out the developers of the library did think of this and had a header file i could use in an intermediary library project which I could then use for my project.